# php function to clean up usernames and passwords passed via a url

Tags: php, mysql, url

I'm trying to escape invalid characters on php. While also trying the php class called ezsql.
Here's my code:

```
<?php

include_once('ez_sql_core.php');
include_once('ez_sql_mysql.php');

$db = new ezSQL_mysql('root','pword','db','localhost');



$uname=$db->escape($_GET['uname']);
$pword=$db->escape($_GET['pword']);


$db->query("INSERT INTO users(Uname, Hpword) VALUES('$uname','$pword')");

?>
```

How do I avoid producing a url like this. And not mess up the whole query. 
http://localhost/folder/file.php?uname=uzer's^&*%#&pword=dd'$#$%#'s

Comment: So what is the actual issue? Nothing will be found since it is wrong name and wrong password.

Comment: The code is saving to the database, but your question is about producing a URL.

Comment: You should not pass user authentication credentials via URL.

Comment: the value for the pword isn't inserted. since the url has two & in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you would use [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function:

```
$uname=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['uname']);
$pword=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pword']);
```

But since escaping is the part of the framework you use, you already have this in your code:

```
$uname=$db->escape($_GET['uname']);
$pword=$db->escape($_GET['pword']);
```

I can guess, that those lines do the trick, so nothing else is needed.

Answer (score -2):

```
$uname = preg_replace("#[^a-zA-Z0-9]#", "", $_GET["uname"]); // removes everything non-alphanumeric
```

But you need to define what "invalid" characters are.

Comment: User will be very surprised to see, that his username that was saved differes from what he has entered.

Comment: There is no reason to check this during authentication process.

Comment: Where do you see authentication? He should use preg_match to check if username matches allowed chars.